# How to use xarray to concatenate along a new dimension while preserving the other dimensions

Tags: python, concatenation, python-xarray

I have a dictionary of several 3d arrays which I would like to concatenate into a single 4d array.

```
<xarray.DataArray 'q' (time: 12, latitude: 129, longitude: 121)>
```

When I concatenate the arrays I get:

```
stack=xr.concat([reshape_shum[i] for i in np.arange(1980,2000)], 'years')
print(stack)
<xarray.DataArray 'q' (years: 20, time: 240, latitude: 129, longitude: 121)>
```

Is it possible to preserve the time dimension so as to get the following?

```
<xarray.DataArray 'q' (years: 20, time: 12, latitude: 129, longitude: 121)>
```

I know I can get this shape with:

```
stack=np.stack(reshape_shum[i] for i in np.arange(1980,2020))
stack.shape
(20, 12, 129, 121)
```

Comment: What do your time dimensions look like? If they have the same coordinate values across all DataArrays they should not be concatenated. Probably you have to convert time to day of year or something like that

Comment: May I ask what is contained in the `time` dimension? If I understand correctly, you would want it to be an ID representing the months. Can you check whether there is an element in this dimension which could represent the year? I.E. if `"01/03/1990"` is somewhat similar to what you have, then it is normal that you end up with 240 values in this dimension (`12 * 20 = 240`); on the other hand, what you will want to have is something like the following: `"01/03"` or `3`... Ultimately, you will want the `time` values to be consistent through the years.

Comment: Thank you! My time was in datetime64. I have changed it to integers and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to solve my issue. My time dimension was datetime64 and I changed this to integers as follows:

```
for i in np.arange(1980,2000):
reshape_shum[i].coords['time']=np.arange(1,13)
stack=xr.concat([reshape_shum[i] for i in np.arange(1980,2000)],  pd.Index(np.arange(1980,2000), name='years'))
print(stack)
<xarray.DataArray 'q' (years: 20, time: 12, latitude: 129, longitude: 121)>
```